# Is there a siddur that has Ta'amei Mikra (trup) in it

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, trop-cantillation

I'm looking to buy a siddur that has the Ta'amim (trup) printed in all parts of davening.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know of any but I am seeking to help this question by asking you to add which _nusach_ you are looking for, or is it truly any _nusach_?

Comment: Do you mean trop on all the parts of davening that are quoted from Tanach, or trop imposed on all the text?

Comment: I'm looking for nusach ashkenaz, and I only want the trup on parts of davening from tanach.

Answer (score 1):

R' Rallis Wiesenthal's siddur, *Tefilloh Sefas Yisroel*, is available on [OpenSiddur](https://opensiddur.org/compilations/liturgical/siddurim/kol-bo/siddur-bnei-ashkenaz-a-german-rite-siddur-prepared-by-r-rallis-wiesenthal/) and follows the Western Ashkenazi nusach. He includes trop on every instance where three or more words are quoted from Tana"ch (with some practical exceptions, such as the phrase ברוך אתה ה׳, which only has trop printed when one would bow during the 'Amidah)

My personal correspondences with R' Wiesenthal however notes that the info in the webpage "Minhag Bad Homburg" is incorrect, as it follows the nearby Frankfurt minhag (with corrections based on the work of R' Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger of [Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz](https://moreshesashkenaz.org/en/)).